# How can I copy a file to a new location, creating the directory as well

Tags: command-line, files, directory, copy

I want to `cp` a file to another directory but that directory doesn't exist yet.

So I would do:

```
mkdir /new_place
cp the_file /new_place
```

Can I do this in one?
I imagine something like `cp the_file -m /new_place` if "m" stood for "make dir's that don't exist"

Would this be a chance to use scp, rsync or another copying utility?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With `--parents` you can recreate the directories from the source to the destination. For example:

```
cp --parents ~/Downloads/test.txt ~/Desktop/
```

Will create the subdirectories `~/Desktop/home/desgua/Downloads` and then copy `test.txt` into it; and

```
cp --parents Downloads/test.txt ~/Desktop/
```

will create `~/Desktop/Downloads`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the following command

```
# rsync --recursive the_file /path/to/your/dir/that/doesn't/exists/
```

**Note: Use of "/" at the end of path:**

- When using "/" at the end of source, rsync will copy the content of the last folder.
  When not using "/" at the end of source, rsync will copy the last folder and the content of the folder.
- When using "/" at the end of destination, rsync will paste the data inside the last folder.
  When not using "/" at the end of destination, rsync will create a folder with the last destination folder name and paste the data inside that folder.

Comment: If you want `the_file` you need to add a `/` to the end of your new directory path.

Answer (score 1):

[desgua's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/124545/295286) is proper and simple way, but what if you need a protable way ? [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html)  defines `cp` without `--parent` flag, so it's not gonna work across all systems.

One option is to write it in Python if it's installed on the system:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from os import makedirs
from os.path import exists,basename
from shutil import copyfile
from sys import argv

if len(argv) < 3:
   print('Not enough args',file=stderr)
   exit(1)

filename = basename(argv[2])
dirs = argv[2].replace(filename,'')
makedirs(dirs)
copyfile(argv[1],argv[2])
```

This works as so:

```
$ ./mkdircp.py /etc/passwd $HOME/foodir/bardir/passwd.copy
$ stat --printf "%F\n" $HOME/foodir/bardir/passwd.copy
regular file
$ head -n 1 $HOME/foodir/bardir/passwd.copy
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily type two commands by using ;.
For instance:

```
mkdir folder; cp file.html folder
```

and it should work.